# Spring: Using @Qualifier with Property Placeholder

Tags: spring

I am trying to use a property placeholder as the attribute for @Qualifier, as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("${beanName}")
private MyBean myBean;
```

However, this does not work, even though the property placeholder is available as a String value:

```
@Value("${beanName}")
private String beanName;
```

What would be a good workaround here, thanks very much.

Comment: A good workaround depends on your overall goal. So what general problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I am using a Spring 3 ProprtySource to pass the name of the bean in to the context when it is loaded. This is the key: the bean name must be passed into the application context as an argument. The argument is recognized by the @Value annotation, but not by Qualifier.

Comment: But why? It could be there are better suited alternatives to your goal. If I had to take a blind guess it sounds like Spring 3.1's bean profiles might suit what you're aiming for.

Comment: The bean name which I need to pass in to the application context cannot be known until the time the spring context is loaded, because it is retrieved from another application.  So somehow I need to pass that string in, and use it in @Qualifier - or achieve the same thing in another way.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered exactly same issue. Just use [Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resources.html)

```
@Resource(name="${beanName}")
private MyBean myBean;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment so this is my answer:

As Adam B said maybe you can use spring profiles to achieve the result you are aiming to (wich result are you aiming?).

Another thing you can do is:

configure a map (using the spring util namespace) in your xml context configuration like this:

```
 <util:map id="mapId" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.xxx.interface-or-superclass">
        <beans:entry key="${property.bean.name.1}" value-ref="bean1-defined-elsewehere"/>
        <beans:entry key="${property.bean.name.2}" value-ref="bean2-defined-elsewehere"/>
        <beans:entry key="${property.bean.name.3}" value-ref="bean3-defined-elsewehere"/>
  </util:map>
```

then you can load this map in a bean called eg. "com.xxx.BeanSelector"

```
@Value("#{mapId}")
private Map<String, com.xxx.interface-or-superclass> myMap;
```

and add to this bean a methos like this:

```
public interface-or-superclass getBean(String beanName){
    return myMap.get(beanName);
}
```

ok now you can have your final class similar to this:

```
@Autowired
private BeanSelector beanSelector;

@Value("${property.name.the.bean.you.want.to.use}")
private String beanName;

private interface-or-superclass myBean;
```

then you can istantiate myBean (maybe inside the method afterPropertiesSet() if you are implementing the interface InitializingBean)

in this way:

```
myBean = beanSelector.getBean(beanName);
// then check ifthe bean is not null or something like that
```

Ok it's a little messy and maybe you can act in a different way based on what you want achieve, but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just a try (don't really known the problem to solve) . You can use fixed bean name as usual (autowire with placeholder is not supported) but you can load different bean implementation from different xml based on property value.
   . 
Else think about a solution based on bean alias. 
My 2 cents