# SpEL in @Qualifier refer to same bean

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am interested to inject a bean reference, which is resolved based on another property on the same bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("#{'prefix' + actualQualifier}")
private OtherBean otherBean

private String actualQualifier;
```

This would ensure that the relationship between "actualQualifier" and "otherBean" is correct.

There is a number of beans configured of the type `OtherBean`.

I can make sure that "actualQualifier" has a value set before autowiring/injection begins.

I am unable to find any way to reference another property value (in the JavaBean sense) on the same bean that is currently being autowired.

Comment: You can make your own `BeanPostProcessor` (or `MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor`) for injecting such beans.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this will not work. SpEL has no access to variables of the enclosing class. And anyway, it looks like `@Qualifier` does not process SpEL expressions.

I did some tests and never found how to use a SpEL expression as a `@Qualifier` value. [This page](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/130370-does-qualifier-work-with-properties-set-using-spring-3-profiles) from Spring forums (and the error messages from Spring) let me think that in fact `@Qualifier` only takes a String and does not try to evaluate a SpEL expression.

My conclusion is that way will lead you in a dead end.

As suggested in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216722/3545273), I think you'd better use a selector bean and set `otherBean` in an init method :

```
@Bean(initMethod="init")
class MyBean {
...
    @Autowired
    private BeanSelector beanSelector;
    private OtherBean otherBean
    private String actualQualifier;

    public void init() {
        otherBean = beanSelector(actualQualifier);
    }
...
}
```

and put all intelligence about the choice of `otherBean` in `beanSelector`.

Comment: That just moved the problem. Then I would need N x qualifierName beans, and no need to know which to use. The main point is that there is N different bean "pairs" that need to find each other somehow.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe : it is even worse than that :-( . But see my edit for another way to get it done.