# Decide which of multiple implementations to use in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring

Given two (or more) implementations of a particular service API, what's the best way to pick which one to use at runtime in my app based on an application property?

Example API:

```
public interface Greeting {
    String sayHello(String username);
}
```

Implementations:

```
public class FriendlyGreeting implements Greeting {
    public String sayHello(String username) {
        return "Hello, " + username;
    }
} 

public class HostileGreeting implements Greeting {
    public String sayHello(String username) {
        return "Go away, " + username;
    }
}
```

I've got a separate service class with an `@Autowired` constructor that takes an instance of `Greeting`.  What I want, is based upon a configuration property, to decide which greeting implementation gets injected and used.  I came up with using a configuration class to make that decision:

```
@Configuration
public class GreetingConfiguration {
    private String selection;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingConfiguration(@Value("${greeting.type}") String type) {
        this.selection = type;
    }

    @Bean
    public Greeting provideGreeting() {
        if ("friendly".equals(selection)) {
            return new FriendlyGreeting();
        } else {
            return new HostileGreeting();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the *right* way to do what I want?   I went down the road of using `@Qualifier` on the implementations, and ended up with a mess where Spring saw 3 instances of my `Greeting` API, and I needed a configuration anyway to pick which implementation to use and return it with a unique qualifier name on it, and that feels worse than what I settled on.

Comment: Does it have to be a configuration property or can it be a Spring profile? Because using a Profile would be the nice and calm *Springy* way to do this. After that, depending on profile, you would provide either Hostile or Friendly Configuration to handle the bean.

Comment: Specifically: have suitable  `@Profile` annotations on your components and pass the `spring.profiles.active` and/or `spring.profiles.include` property at runtime...

Comment: I'll look into profiles, but I think they're defined by environment that we deploy the app into and not really changeable.

Comment: Also possibly helpful is using `@Conditional` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351004/2958086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

[@Compass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass) and [@user268396](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268396/user268396) were correct - using Profiles got this working as expected.

I created both implementations, annotated with @Service and @Profile("friendly") or @Profile("hostile"), and could change the property `spring.profiles.active` to `dev,friendly` for example, and get what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Conditional` annotations described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html and https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/

`@Profile` annotations mentioned above are based upon `@Conditional`(from Spring Framework); see also Spring Boot: [`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can mark both Greeting as @Service and select the chosen one with @Qualifier("yourServiceHere") like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("friendlyGreeting")
private Greeting greeting;
```

Another way you can do it is with profile. You can mark your FriendlyGreeting service with @Service and @Profile("friendly") and the HostileGreeting service with @Service and @Profile("hostileGreeting") and just put in the application.properties the following:

```
spring.profiles.active=friendly
```

Comment: i doubt, that SpEL works in qualifier... (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773117/592355)

Comment: Good thought, but the evaluation of `"${app.greeting}"` doesn't happen, and spring goes looking for a bean with the literal qualifier name of `${app.greeting}`

Comment: So you can put your qualifier as a string @Qualifier("friendlyGreeting")

Comment: so you cannot manage which implementation to use at runtime without using Profile: Qualifier("friendlyGreeting") is hardcoded; and Qualifier("${app.greetig}") won't work. Is that correct, Profile is the only way (except initial solution in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full solution using ideas mentioned by David and Vitor above with @Profile and @Qualifer annotations.

Two beans with same name but Only one is activated based on which profile is defined.

```
@Profile("profile1")
@Bean("greeting")
public class FriendlyGreeting implements Greeting {

---

@Profile("profile2")
@Bean("greeting")
public class HostileGreeting implements Greeting {

---

@Configuration
public class GreetingConfiguration {

    private Greeting greeting;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingConfiguration(@Qualifier("greeting") Greeting greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

}
```

Notes:

- you can remove the intermediate class `GreetingConfiguration` and stick the "greeting" bean wherever you need
- i prefer the @Autowired on the constructor instead of the class member to make it easier for unit testing.